# I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this Array

Tags: c

I'm trying to separate the numbers of a sequence, and store them all in an array.

For what the little I have seen of C, I am doing nothing wrong, and the program compiles perfectly, but the moment it goes to print the numbers, it just doesn't work.

The explanation of what I'm trying to do is in the end.

```c
long int number;
    
do
{
    number = get_long("number:\n");
}
while (number<1 || number>9999999999999999);
    
int numbers[16], n;
//We separate the numbers, from right to left
for (long int I=10; I>100000000000000000; I*=10)
{
    for (long int J=1; J>100000000000000000; J*=10)
    {
        for (n=0; n>16; n++)
        {
            numbers[n]=(number%I)/J;
        }
    }
}
    
printf("%i\n", numbers[1]);
```

It is supposed to accept numbers of 1 digit up until 16 digits, and separate each digit.

For example, if we had `16`, it would separate `1` and `6` into two digits, making the `6` the first digit, and the `1` the second, so it would start counting from right to left. It's supposed to store each digit in an array of 16 spaces. Then I would just print the second digit, just to make sure it does work, but when I run it, it just gives me `0`; meaning it doesn't work, but I see no problem with it.

It probably is that I'm either too inexperienced, or I don't have the necessary knowledge, to be able to see the problem in the code.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include a [mcve] here, but if you consider using a string array to capture the "number', then each array element can be obtained by recognizing that `val` = arrar[i] - '0'.

Comment: First off, all of your loop conditions are backwards. should be `I<100000000000000000`, not `I>100000000000000000` and so on for the others. The loops never run because it immediately evaluates to false

Comment: (1) The conditions in the `for` loops are false from the beginning (2) Try to ask yourself how many times the assignment in the inner loop is executed.

Comment: If you want to work with a number as digits, and especially if you are using the Luhn algorithm to check credit card “numbers”, then you should read the digits as individual characters, not as a big integer. The `long` type in a C implementation cannot always represent 16 digit-numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - _"long type in a C implementation cannot always represent 16 digit-numbers."_.    Can it ever?  (range of `long` is `-2147483648 to 2147483647`)

Comment: @ryyker: Per C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1, `LONG_MIN` must be −2,147,483,647 or less and `LONG_MAX` MUST BE +2,147,483,647 or greater. There are no limits beyond those; a C implementation may make `long` capable of representing values as much beyond those as it chooses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have incorrect loop termination checks, so the loops are never entered.
- After reversing `>` to `<`, you end up evaluating the body of the inner loop 16*16*16 = 4096 times even though there are only 16 digits. There should only be one loop of 16 iterations.
- A `long int` is not is only guaranteed to support numbers up to `2,147,483,647`. Instead, use one of `long long int`, `int_least64_t` or `int64_t`, or one of their unsigned counterparts.

You were attempting to write the following:

```c
uint64_t mod = 10;  // Formerly named I
uint64_t div = 1;   // Formerly named J
for (int n=0; n<16; ++n) {
   numbers[n] = ( number % mod ) / div;
   mod *= 10;
   div *= 10;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YEqWaPeWe)

But that's a bit more complicated than needed. Let's swap the order of the division and modulus.

```c
uint64_t div = 1;
for (int n=0; n<16; ++n) {
   numbers[n] = ( number / div ) % 10;
   div *= 10;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dvzrddEdh)

Finally, we can simplify a bit more if we don't mind clobbering `number` in the process.

```c
for (int n=0; n<16; ++n) {
   numbers[n] = number % 10;
   number /= 10;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/89Eexcroq)

Comment: Thank you sir, helped me a lot. I cannot give an up vote because I don't have enough reputation, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If using a `long` variable, the value ranges are: `-2147483648 to 2147483647` (in most C implementations, as noted by @Eric P in comments)

So the expression `while (number<1 || number>9999999999999999);` (and similar) do not make sense.  As a number, `number` will never approach `9999999999999999`.  Same for expression: `...J>100000000000000000; J*=10)`.  (and its really moot at this point, but `>` should be `<`)

Consider using a string approach:

Using a null terminated char array (C string) to hold initial value, the essential steps are pretty straight forward and could include the following:

```
char number[17];//room for 16 characters + null terminator

scanf("%16s", number);//string comprised of maximum of 16 digits

len = strlen(number);
int num_array[len];//using VLA
memset(num_array, 0, sizeof num_array);//zero array
for(int i = 0;i < len; i++)
{
     if(number[i] < '0' || number[i] > '9') break;//qualify input. Break if non-numeric
     num_array = number[i] - '0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, since I barely know anything about the language C, I dont understand some of the things you put in the code, but when still helped me a lot, and when I'm done wiht my mini project I'm going to search for these things I don't know, still, thanks a lot!.     By the way, I can not give up vote because I dont have enough reputation, lol.

Answer (score 0):

All of your `for` loops are using `operator>` when they should be using `operator<` instead.  Thus the loop conditions are always false (`10` is not `>` than `100000000000000000`, `1` is not `>` than `100000000000000000`, `0` is not `>` than `16`), so the loops don't get entered at all, and thus `numbers[]` is left unfilled.

Fixing that, you still have a logic problem.  Think of what the result of `(number%I)/J` is when `number` is `16` and `I` and `J` are large values.  The result of `operator/` is typically `0`!  On some loop iterations, `numbers[]` gets populated with correct values.  But other iterations will then overwrite `numbers[]` with `0`s.  Once all of the loops are finished, only the `0`s are left.

This [Online Demo](https://ideone.com/57alxm) demonstrates this in action.

Comment: Thank you!, I cannot give up vote bacuse I don't have enough reputation yet, jaja.